# JavaScript Quiz Code Error

Tags: javascript

It's a simple JavaScript quiz code and I've found that while it's mostly functional, once I answer only one question and then proceed to put blank answers on the rest, the quiz computes it as half of the the total value.

For example; if I answer only one question out of 4 questions, it tells me that I have 2 out of 4 questions correct despite not answering the others. I'm sorta confused by this and I need some clarification.

What do I specifically need to add? And could anyone explain why? I got this quiz code from [Adam Khoury's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_UuOVhuCF8),

```
<html>
    <title> HTML Quiz </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
    var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
    var questions = [
      ["What does HTML stand for?", "Hypertext Markup Language", "Hypertrain Master Language", "Hypertext Marking Language", "A"],
      ["What was Java's first project name?", "Mocha", "Perseus", "Green", "C"],
      ["This programming language was the predecessor of Java, developed by James Gosling", "C++", "Oak", "Python", "B"],
      ["What does CSS stand for?", "Cascading Style Sheet", "Calculating Solutions Sheet", "Computer String Sheet", "A"],
      ["What was the dominant programming language before Java was created?", "C#", "C++", "Python", "B"],
      ["Can CSS be used in tandem with HTML and Java?", "True", "False", "Neither", "A"],
      ["What is the main foundation of all programming language?", "Binary/Machine Language", "Logic", "Code", "A"]
    ];
    function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
    }
    function renderQuestion() {
    test = _("test");
    if (pos >= questions.length) {

    test.innerHTML = "<h2> You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct </h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed!";
    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    return false;

    }
     _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
     question = questions[pos][0];
     chA = questions[pos][1];
     chB = questions[pos][2];
     chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' required value='A'>"+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' required value='B'>"+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' required value='C'>"+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";  
    }
    function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
    choice = choices[i].value;
             }
        }
        if (choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
        }
        pos++;
        renderQuestion();
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
    </script>
    <style>  
    div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px; }  
    </style>
    <body>
    <center>
    <h2 id="test_status"> </h2>
    <div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: Try answering just one question and just keep pressing submit answer without answering the other questions

Comment: @J.Daveo to work with larger code you should use jsfiddle site so user can easily debug your codes.

Comment: Update : got the issue. Correcting

Comment: @ShahariaAzam Noted! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @SagarV Thanks for the help sir! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

#### As said in comment, I found the issue but unable to post because of some restrictions. The solution is below

A simple mistake you have done and I corrected it.

> You didn't declare `choice='';` at the beginning of the `function checkAnswer`. Also you didn't used the keyword `var` to make it local. So it will be compiled as `window.choice` and is global.
>   In the `for loop` in the `function`, you check that the `checked value` of `radio` and if anything found, it is copied and cross checked with the answer.
>   If no answer found, since it is global, the previous value will be there.

**Testing :** 
I clicked the first radio box for the first question and then skipped all the qestions.

**Result :** 
4

**Reason :** 
Since 4 A's are there and we skipped all remaining, the First selected `A` is stored in `choice` and cross checked with `Array answer` each time. So, it will match 4 times.

```js
    var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
    var questions = [
      ["What does HTML stand for?", "Hypertext Markup Language", "Hypertrain Master Language", "Hypertext Marking Language", "A"],
      ["What was Java's first project name?", "Mocha", "Perseus", "Green", "C"],
      ["This programming language was the predecessor of Java, developed by James Gosling", "C++", "Oak", "Python", "B"],
      ["What does CSS stand for?", "Cascading Style Sheet", "Calculating Solutions Sheet", "Computer String Sheet", "A"],
      ["What was the dominant programming language before Java was created?", "C#", "C++", "Python", "B"],
      ["Can CSS be used in tandem with HTML and Java?", "True", "False", "Neither", "A"],
      ["What is the main foundation of all programming language?", "Binary/Machine Language", "Logic", "Code", "A"]
    ];
    function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
    }

    function renderQuestion() {
    
    test = _("test");
    if (pos >= questions.length) {

    test.innerHTML = "<h2> You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct </h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed!";
    
    correct = 0;
    return false;

    }
     _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
     question = questions[pos][0];
     chA = questions[pos][1];
     chB = questions[pos][2];
     chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<form id='qz'><input type='radio' name='choices' required value='A'>"+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' required value='B'>"+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' required value='C'>"+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button></form>";  
    
    }
    function checkAnswer(){
    choice='';
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
    choice = choices[i].value;
             }
        }
        if (choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
        }
        
        _('qz').reset();
        pos++;
        renderQuestion();
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```css
 div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px; }
```

```html
<html>
    <title> HTML Quiz </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <body>
    <center>
    <h2 id="test_status"> </h2>
    <div id="test"></div>
```